# Getting an estimate for monthly installment using dates and balance

Tags: sql, date

I have a bond balance amount outstanding for different properties and the date they were registered in. I just need to add 20 years to the current date and get the months difference between the years then use that to divide the bond balance in order to get an estimate for the installment. Now a bond can only be granted if it will only take 30% of your salary so this means I must assume that the installment calculated is the 30% of the income. Now the income=100/30 * monthly installment. Now my questions if why did I need to add 20 years when I could have multiplied 20*12=240 to get the months difference for any bond given and does this rather mean I should get today's date and use that to add the 20 years then use that to cal the months difference to get the installment.

I am so confused if it makes sense. Has anyone done similar calculations ?

Comment: Is this specific to some programming language?

Comment: sql yes. but also when i use 100/30 * (MonthlyInstal) where monthlyinstal is the approx 30% . i am trying to get 70% of the given 30% monthlyinstal. works if i use a calculator but in sql gives me only 90% of the total.

Answer (score -1):

Alter table Absa..Jan14
Add RegDate as (case when isdate(Bnd_RegDate) = 1 then cast(Bnd_RegDate as date)  end)

Alter table Absa..Jan14 
Add EndDate date

Update Absa..Jan14 
Set EndDate = DateAdd(yy, 20, Cast(RegDate As date))

Alter table Absa..Jan14 
Add TotalMonth tinyint

Update Absa..Jan14 
Set TotalMonth = DATEDIFF(Month,RegDate,Enddate)

Alter table Absa..Jan14 
Add MonthlyInst money

Alter table Absa..Jan14 
Add Bond_Balance numeric(18,2)

update Absa..Jan14
set Bond_Balance=abs(account_balance)

Update Absa..Jan14 
Set MonthlyInst = (Bond_Balance/TotalMonth)

Alter table Absa..Jan14 
Add Income money

Update Absa..Jan14 
Set Income = (100/30) * MonthlyInst  /*  i get 90% of the monthlyinst
*/